# Rails search query are build wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a model object called Business this one has many BusinessPlace and a business place has many BusinessPlacePhone. For BusinessPlacePhone in the database is created a column named BusinessPlace_id but when i try using the BusinessPlace.BusinessPlacePhones property to get all the phones for a business place the select query is looking like this

```
SELECT "business_place_phones".* FROM "business_place_phones"  WHERE "business_place_phones"."business_place_id" = 1
```

But the query should search in the BusinessPlace_id column because this one exists.
And i get

```
SQLException: no such column: business_place_phones.business_place_id:
```

What is the problem, why rails is building the table in the database in one way and search queries in another way ?

I try manually rename the column and works for queries but is not respecting the model properties.

There is any way to solve this problem or should i just rename the model with only one name, this way BusinessPlace become Place and BusinessPlacePhone become Phone ?

Comment: I've manage to fix it by set to the model at has_one BusinessPlace the foreign key attribute :foreign_key => 'BusinessPlace_id'

Answer (score 0):

Rails uses underscore in such situations.

You definetly shouldn't name anything by using CamelCase and underscore combined.

Actually, unless it's a class name, forget about CamelCase and stick with underscore, don't name your fields `BusinessPlace_id` or `BusinessPlaceId` or anything like that, use `business_place_id` instead.

For more naming conventions read this link [here](http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=7)

Then your problems will be gone. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't have fields named with underscore when i used the scaffold command to create models that was the generated table schema for BusinessPlacePhone. I used rails g scaffold Business , rails g scaffold BusinessPlace Business:references , rails g scaffold BusinessPlacePhone BusinessPlace:references .

Comment: check your migrations. make sure the columns are named correctly, with underscore